# How to save image in django Object storage

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to upload my images to the file storage(aws storage) and thumbnails of that image to media root folder. This is my code and I want that i can download the image from file storage, but i am not able to download the files from file storage as media_root is set at the location of the media root folder.

This is my settings.py code :

```
# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

This is my download function code :

```
def download(request,id):
previous_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
if request.method == 'POST':
    recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
    data = {
        'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
        'response': recaptcha_response
    }
    r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
    result = r.json()
    ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

    if result['success']:
        image = Image.objects.get(id=id)
        file_name = os.path.basename(image.image.name)
        file_path = image.image.name
        fl = storage.open(file_path, "rb")
        content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)[0]
        response = HttpResponse(fl, content_type=content_type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
        response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(file_path)
        return response
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
        return redirect(previous_url)
else:
    return redirect(previous_url)
```

Please refer the error image while download the image :

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8WXH.png)

Comment: This error shows that `there is no folder named ________` . So , make a folder according to the `Error`

Comment: My downloadable image is in Object Storage but the error is showing the "directory not found on server". What can i do in my code so that it can download file from object storage without error.

Also. My image thumbnails are stored on server and downloadable files on object storage.

Comment: Try to display image in `template` , Is it showing ?

Comment: I tried to debug line by line, the error came on :-

fl = storage.open(file_path, "rb")